# Disable product attribute from admin edit in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, admin-panel, enable-disable

I have create an attribute `viewed_count`, I will write a code to update it from observer.

Now I don't want anyone to edit it from admin, So I want to make it disabled from admin edit.

How can I achieve it? Please help me find solution on this.

Comment: IMHO you should think about, if you really want to solve it this way. you're saving the product everytime someone visits the detail page. that sounds so unperformant. how will you deal with race-conditions?

Comment: In that case I can make a cronjob that will get all the visited data and update product count at day end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Attribute can be disabled on form if you add `disabled` attribute on `textbox`

You can do it by javascript.

Add `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_edit.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Vendor_Module::js/custom_product_edit.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Add JS file in `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/custom_product_edit.js`

```
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(document).ajaxStop(function () {
            jQuery('input[name=product\\[viewed_count\\]]').prop("disabled",true);
        });
    });
});
```

I don't know if it is a good approach or not, but this is the best solution I can think of.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: Applying this solution

Comment: It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm working under AC (Magento Enterprise) 2.4.* trying to Apply the solution above and didn't work.

I found other solution (seem to be the magento way) using Ui Modifiers here.

https://webkul.com/blog/disable-attribute-in-product-edit-admin-panel-in-magento-2/